# ProgressDialog from other Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, progressdialog

i have 2 Activitys. In the first Updater Activity i want to create a ProgressDialog,
which I want to show in the other Activity(TopRatedFragment). How can i do this?

```
public class Updater extends Activity {

    String pid = "1";
    JSONObject x;
    int success;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int y;
    private String result;
    String Url = "domain.com";
     JSONArray products = null;
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checker);

    }

    public int getResult(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            Log.d("Request: ", json.toString());
            // Getting JSON Array
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.i("Status 2 z", "Status z: "+ success); 
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return success;
     }

    public final int updaten(String site) {

        Update task = new Update();
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", site));
            x = task.execute(params).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        y = getResult(x);

        return y;
    }

class Update extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, String, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Updater.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {

        // Getting JSON from URL

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Url, params[0]);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        Log.d("Updater ", json.toString());

    }
}
```

---

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

This method is called after an OnClickListener.

```
public void Updatequest(final String site) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            ado = new Updater();
            Log.i("Status 2 z", "Status z: " + z);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you really want to report?");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Press Yes to submit your report")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    int z = ado.updaten(site); //call the method in the other Activity
                                    Log.i("Status 1 z", "Status z: " + z);
                                    if (z == 1) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getActivity(),
                                                "Thanks, your report was successfull",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        z = 0;
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getActivity(),
                                                "Please check your Internet connection!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "An error has occured please check your Internet Connection again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
```

If i click on the Button, a lot of errors are shown. The first is the FATAL EXCEPTION: main
and a java.lang.NullPointerException.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Your TopRatedFragment is not an `Activity`. Your `Updater` is an `Activity` but does not manage your `TopRatedFragment`. Why, how and where you get an error is unclear. Before posting that much of unrelevant code, you should have read what Google thinks about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Firstly,you have only one Activity and other is fragment,secondly can you please elaborate what actually you want to do in the code.?

Comment: Everything works fine the JSON code is ok. But I can't get the ProgressDialog from the other Activity. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the logcat, you will find the full exception backtrace. It tells you the line, where the `NullPointerException` was thrown. Please check, if that button really exists. Maybe, it is caused by a wrong ID or something else.

If you have a very loooong backtrace, read through the trace and look for "`Caused by....`" lines. It often happened to me, that the exception was encapsulated and wasn't obvious shown in the logcat.